# Value does not live long enough with explicit lifetime, but does live long enough when omitted

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have the following Rust program which passes a closure to a function generic in a lifetime `'a` and a closure of type `F`, which calls the closure with a reference to some local data:

```
fn other_function<'a, F>(f: F)
    where F: Fn(&'a u32)
{
    let the_value = 0;
    f(&the_value);
}

fn main() {
    other_function(|_| { /* do nothing */ });
}
```

This fails to compile, with the following messages:

```
<anon>:5:8: 5:17 error: `the_value` does not live long enough
<anon>:5     f(&the_value);
                ^~~~~~~~~
<anon>:3:1: 6:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 3:0...
<anon>:3 {
<anon>:4     let the_value = 0;
<anon>:5     f(&the_value);
<anon>:6 }
<anon>:4:23: 6:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 4:22
<anon>:4     let the_value = 0;
<anon>:5     f(&the_value);
<anon>:6 }
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

My minimal example might be a bit *too* minimal now, since for this example a valid solution is to remove `'a,` and `'a`. However, I have a similar situation in a more complicated program in which explicit lifetimes seem required.

Is there a way of specifying lifetimes manually, such that the above program gets accepted by the compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the *caller* of `other_function` gets to pick the lifetime that will fill in `'a`, but you want `other_function` to do it. You could use a bit of syntax called *higher ranked trait bounds*:

```
fn other_function<F>(f: F)
    where F: for <'a> Fn(&'a u32)
{
    let the_value = 0;
    f(&the_value);
}

fn main() {
    other_function(|_| { /* do nothing */ });
}
```

As you pointed out, in this case, it makes more sense to omit the `'a` completely. It's possible that your case needs something more complicated, but with your example nothing else makes sense. The caller cannot possibly specify any lifetime that will be compatible with a stack-allocated variable inside the method you are calling.

Comment: That makes a boatload of sense. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: What is the `for` used for there?

Comment: @Kroltan When I was trying to fix my problem, I figured out I needed to somehow make the `Fn(&'a u32)` be generic over some lifetime `'a`, but I couldn't figure out where to put it. `Fn<'a>(&'a u32)` is obviously wrong. As far as I understand it, the `for`'s purpose is exactly to allow adding a lifetime there.

Comment: @Thierry I see that it defines a lifetime requirement, but I didn't know this syntax.

Comment: "Higher ranked trait bound," sometimes abbreviated as HRTB. It's the only syntax not in the book.